# I have an error in which the server refuses access to static files

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

I have deployed on the server
Ubuntu 22.04 64 bit Django project. Installed and configured Gunicorn and Nginx. I noticed that static files are not loaded. There is such an error in the logs "2023/10/02 09:46:33 [error] 3188#3188: *2 open() "/home/atlet/atlet_site/school/static/css/content-news.css" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 81.177.255.225, server: 77.223.99.162, request: "GET /static/css/content-news.css HTTP/1.1", host: "77.223.99.162", referrer: "http://77.223.99.162/ " the path written in the configuration file is correct, but something prevents nginx from accessing static files. It seems like I didn't install a firewall and the rights seem to be to static files. What other problems can there be?Thank you in advance!

I changed the nginx configuration. The right way . Used Python manage.py collectstatic . Using the "sudo chmod -R 755 /home/atlet/atlet_site/static" command. But the problem was not solved

Comment: Mo the problem was solved there was a problem with the access rights of the current user!!!!!!